# MERN Scaffolding with Authorization

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I'm a senior .NET developer wanting to move into MERN, full-stack. Is there a scaffolding tool that will quickly get me setup and that also supports authorization (register/login features, etc), built-in?

Answer (score 1):

Express development is fairly unopinionated. As a result of that flexibility, there's a lot less built into it than there is in more opinionated framework like Rails for example.

The other thing is that since the MERN stack isn't monolithic, you'll need to set up the front and back ends independently.

The two most common 'scaffolding' tools I've come across in MERN development are [Create React app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) and [Express generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator). These will get you started with a front end and a server that will run immediately, but for things like auth, you'll either need to build your own, or install packages that will handle it for you.

I've seen open source templates on Github that you can start with, but since things change so fast, I personally don't like the idea of starting off with someone else's outdated code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For whoever lands on this page like I did.

I found two option for MERN scaffolding. The first is deprecated and the second seems to be abandoned and/or incomplete:

1. mern-cli (http://npmjs.com/package/mern-cli) (DEPRECATED)
2. mern (http://npmjs.com/package/mern) (ABANDONED)

My solution was to keep my React UI and Express API on separate directory, say "ui" and "server", in my project's root directory.

Then I use the cors module (http://npmjs.com/package/cors) to handle cross site resource sharing for development environment only, so that my react app can talk to my express server, which is running on a different port during development, like this (in server.js)

```
const cors = require('cors');
if (app.get('env').trim() == 'development') {
  app.use(cors());
}
```

For production I just run a batch script that copies all the files from my ui/build directory to server/public directory after the react build process is complete. The scripts section of my package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "postbuild": "copy-build.bat",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

And the content of batch file reference in the postbuild key is

```
xcopy "build\*" "..\server\public" /s /y
```

If you prefer or have to use a bash script instead you can make a copy-build.sh file with the content

```
cp -r build/* ../server/public
```